# Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client vs System.Data.SqlServerCe

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

I am writing a vb application that uses tableadapters.

I want to use the connection property of the tableadapters.

I have the following code:

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

    Dim tbladaptBirds as TestBirdDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblBirdsTableAdapter
    Dim tbladptrVetLinks As New TestBirdDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblVetLinksTableAdapter
    Dim tbladptrVets As New TestBirdDBDataSetTableAdapters.tblVetsTableAdapter

    Dim con As New SqlCeConnection

   tbladaptBirds.Connection = con
```

This gives me the following error:
Value of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.SqlCeConnection'.

When I replaced  Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe with Imports Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client, the error went away.

I was just playing around with a new project, and I typed in the following code

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

    Dim con As New SqlCeConnection
    Dim tbladptr As New DatasetTestDataSetTableAdapters.tblInfoTableAdapter

    tbladptr.Connection = con  ' no error
```

Why do I need Imports Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client in the application I am writing while Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe is what I need in the application I was playing around with?

Thanks

Comment: It may have to do with the version. Microsoft no longer develop SQL Server CE so the provider may have been removed from the `System` namespace, which is for core .NET types, and moved out to the `Microsoft` namespace, which is for other Microsoft products.  It could also be the other way around, i.e. SQL Server CE was not considered core initially but that changed.

Comment: I don't that has anything to do with it. I'm running VS 2012, and both programs are on the same computer.